AWS CLI V2 running but not displaying output in GIT BASH
I am using AWS CLI V2 in my Windows 11 and use GIT BASH as a terminal. I configured the AWS within the terminal but command "aws iam list-users" is running successfully but not showing the output in the terminal which is weird
I tried to re-install AWS CLI.

Does aws sts get-caller-identity yield any output? Does aws iam list-users --debug yield any clues?

Had no success with "aws iam list-users --debug" and with "aws sts get-caller-identity"

I'd be tempted to uninstall and reinstall the awscli. If you run a simple python script e.g. python -c "print('hello')", does it work?

No, when I run "python -c "print('hello')", it says python not found

I reinstalled the python version, now it is running.
